# I don't understand DataSource and DataContextProxy

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to create a context menu, I already have working buttons in my XAML although I don't know how to translate it to C# to create my context menu. I don't understand how DataSource and DataContextProxy work, here's a piece of the code I'm working with,

```
<sr:Button Text="Deactivate" Size="Medium" SmallImage="/Fsc.Feenics.Clients.Silverlight2;component/Images/16/deactivate.png" Command="{Binding Path=DataSource.DeactivateCardCommand, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfTrue}}" />
```

This is my attempt to translate it to C# for my context menu

```
  contextMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = "Deactivate", Command = new RelayCommand<Guid>((x) => localContext.DeactivateCard(x)), CommandParameter = objectInfo.Id });
```

I'm not sure where to put the DataSource/DataContextProxy in my C#, if anyone could give me any suggestions or explain how it works it would be greatly apperciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you understand the xaml, so I will explain from beginning...

Your button command is binding to a class StaticResource object which has a x:key "DataConextProxy".

That object is a class that expose a property: DataSource

And that DataSource object is a class that expose a Command: DeactivateCardCommand

From the name of DataContextProxy, I will assume is about [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx).

Bascially just create the Menu Item with using same binding on command, same binding path and it will be fine...